# Setting a fixed list.phtml and view.phtml in magento template?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm working on a big multisite + multitemplate (based on a same base-template) installation of magento 1.7, and have bumped into problem: 
On a sub-domained template I don't know from where does magento take the list.phtml and view.phtml when it generates the pages with the list of products. 
Can this be set-up per template, that it is hard-coded to get the list+view.phtml from the template\catalog\product\ path of the templates' app folder?

Thanks.
Gas

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that it was the problem of the plugin used at other sub-sites (which replaced the list.phtml and view.phtml), but I deleted it on the working-site.

I've put the same plugin files also to the sub-site's template folder, and it finds the correct files now.

BR-:G